# Why was my question related to kernel hacking closed?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, specific-question, reopen-closed

I have asked [this question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12305162/kernel-hacking-methodology-how-to-find-out-where-to-hack-the-linux-kernel). It seems people want to close this. I've asked for clarification and I've been given the following link: https://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask.

However I don't see anything there which sustains their action. On the contrary, the document states:

> However, if your motivation is “I would like others to explain ______ to me”, then you are probably OK.

The question is a programming question (it is about hardware, so some elements of hardware come into play, but there's the **linux-kernel** tag too), it is constructive, since I'm trying to build something, AND it is of general interest, since I'm asking about the general methodology, not about specifics to my system.

So why close this question?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think that two comments for that question explain why the question was closed, even if the reason is not the one I would have expected.

> The problem may be (I didn't vote to close, and I even upvoted) that this is a very wide question. It's not off topic in my opinion but asking for " the methodology, step by step, with reasons for each step" may be a little out of the custom here. – [dystroy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/263525/dystroy)

> Even though it's a programming question, it's very open ended and difficult to impossible to provide you with an authoritative answer that is both specific enough for your needs and general enough to be applicable to a wider audience.  – [OmnipotentEntity](https://stackoverflow.com/users/483486/omnipotententity)

The [FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask) says:

> You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face. Chatty, open-ended questions diminish the usefulness of our site and push other questions off the front page.
>
> **Your questions should be reasonably scoped.** If you can imagine an entire book that answers your question, you're asking too much.

While you are asking a question for a problem you are facing, the question is not reasonably scoped. If you were writing a driver, and you had a problem with part of the code, which is not working as expected, a question about that would be more scoped.

Answer (score 7):

I can't really tell *exactly* what you're asking about in that question, but it doesn't appear to be a programming question. You were talking about your laptop, I didn't see anything related to programming except the mention that you want to learn about this *to make a program*. So your question is not actually *about* programming, but just information leading up to a program you're going to write in the future. Stack Overflow is not the place to talk about hardware. Try [Super User](http://superuser.com).

> [**What kinds of questions can I ask here?**](https://stackoverflow.com/faq#questions)
>
> - a specific programming problem
> - a software algorithm
> - software tools commonly used by programmers
> - practical, answerable problems that are unique to the programming profession